# Set UISwitches by JSON data?

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I want to set some UISwitches to values pulled in by a HTTP GET request. The request is working. However, since I'm fairly new to iOS programming I don't know how to go from having some JSON data to pulling it apart like in PHP.

This is what I currently have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewdidload");
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.test.api/setings"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];
    [mutableRequest addValue:_xAuthToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];

    request = [mutableRequest copy];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [switch1 setOn:1 animated:NO];
    [switch2 setOn:1 animated:NO];
    [switch3 setOn:1 animated:NO];
    [switch4 setOn:1 animated:NO];
    [switch5 setOn:1 animated:NO];
    [switch6 setOn:1 animated:NO];
    [switch7 setOn:0 animated:NO];
    [switch8 setOn:1 animated:NO];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    // show all values
    for(id key in res) {

        id value = [res objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }

    // extract specific value...
    NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"results"];

    for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
        NSString *icon = [result objectForKey:@"icon"];
        NSLog(@"icon: %@", icon);
    }

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

And this is what it's getting back from the server:

```
{"data":
    {"setting1":"1",
     "setting2":"1",
     "setting3":"0",
     "setting4":"0",
     "setting5":"0",
     "setting6":"0",
     "setting7":"0",
     "setting8":"0"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the 1 or 0 number string to bool value and then set the switch state using it

//Declare this array of switches in your class header file

```
property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray *switches;
```

and initialize it in ViewDidLoad method

```
switches=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:switch1,switch2,switch3,switch4,switch5,switch6,switch7,switch8,nil];
```

// and in your - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection method

```
 NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
```

//get the array of settings and values from the data Object in your json

```
NSDictionary *switchValues=[res objectForKey:@"data"];
    // show all values
NSUInteger *switchIndex=0;
```

//iterate and convert the value to bool and set the switch state using that value

```
    for(id key in switchValues) {

        id value = [switchValues objectForKey:key];   
        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;
        [[switches objectAtIndex:switchIndex] setOn:[valueAsString boolValue] animated:NO];
        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
        switchIndex++;

    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds dumb, but I don't know how to implement your code into mine...

Comment: In your loop when u r getting objects for your keys the objects returned are nsstrings like for the key "setting1" you would get "1". To set the switch state using it you can just convert that to bool value where 1 converts to true/Yes and 0 converts to false/No and set the value of switch using that by calling the function setOn on that particular switch like I did above

Comment: @user4114789 I edited the answer to match your code :)

Comment: What I get now is `Use of undeclared identifier 'switches'; did you mean 'switch'?`

Comment: u need to declare a nsarray switches property and use that in viewdidload in your class ! the one I declared has scope just inside of viewdidload method